# Why Birt report plugin removes param entries

Tags: grails, birt

This could be silly but I dont understand why this code is included on the [example](http://grails.org/plugin/birt-report):

```
params.remove('action')
params.remove('controller')
params.remove('name')
```

Because ***they are not necessary hence freeing the memory*** or ***they have special meaning when passed to the report engine***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why they are removed is because they Grails related and not related to the report itself. It's removed to keep the log/debug clean and to avoid any confusion downstream in the report itself.

Notice the debugging/logging in the [source code](https://github.com/eyck/grails-birt-report/blob/master/grails-app/services/com/itjw/grails/birt/BirtReportService.groovy).

It won't hurt anything to put them there, provided your reports know to ignore them or understand that they are provided by Grails.

Comment: Clear! I saw the link and has this line: `log.debug "Reportparams:${props}"`. So you are right not good to include them.